# Strange string comparison results after retrieving TEXT value

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding, string-comparison

I'm scraping data from multiple pages and inserting to my MySQL database. There could be duplicates; I only want to store unique entries. Just in case my primary key isn't sufficient, I put in a test which is checked when I get a MySQL 1062 error* (duplicate entry on primary key**). The test checks that all of the pieces of the tuple to be inserted are identical to the stored tuple. What I found is that the when I get the 1062 error that the stored tuple and the scraped tuple are only different by one element/field, a `TEXT` field.

First, I retrieved the already stored entry and passed them both into `htmlspecialchars()` to compare the output visually; they looked identical.

According to `strlen()`, the string retrieved from the DB was 304 characters in length but the newly scraped string was 305. `similar_text()` backed that up by returning 304***.

So then I looped through one string comparing character for character with the other string, stopping when there was a mismatch. The problem was the first character. In the string coming from the DB it was `N` yet both strings appear to start with `I` (even in their output from `htmlspecialchars()`). Plus the DB string was supposedly one character shorter, not longer.

I then checked the output (printing `htmlspecialchars()`) and the `strlen()` again, but this time before the original string (the one that ends up in the DB) is inserted, and before the duplicated is inserted. They looked the same as before and `strlen()` returned 305 for both.

So this made me think their must be something happening between my PHP and my MySQL. So instead of comparing the newly scraped string to the string in the database with the same primary key (the ID), I try to retrieve a tuple where every single field is equal to their respective parts in newly scraped section like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE value1='{$MYSQL_ESCAPED['value1']}' .... AND valueN='{$MYSQL_ESCAPED['valueN']}';` and the tuple is returned. Therefore they are identical in every way including that problematic `TEXT` field.

#### What's going on here?

Straight away when I see `N` in front of string I think of `NVARCHAR`, etc. from MSSQL but as I know that's not a part of MySQL, but...

#### Could it have anything to do with the fact that ["Each TEXT value is stored using a two-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-type-overview.html)?

#### Or does this just point to a character encoding problem?

---

**Edit:**

- There are no multi-byte characters stored in the database.
- `mb_strlen()` returns the same results as `strlen()` where mentioned above.
- Using `utf8_encode()` or `mb_convert_encoding()` before inserting to the DB makes no difference; an invisible `N` is still prefixing the string retrieved from the DB.

---

**Notes**:

- Before inserting any string into my database I pass it through `mysql_real_escape_string(trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str)))` which replaces double spaces with single spaces, removes leading & tailing spaces and escapes it for MySQL insertion.
- The page I print the output & testing to is UTF-8.
- Upon creation, my DB has its character set set to `utf8`, its collation to `utf8_general_ci` and I use the `SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';` command too, as a precaution.
- Foot notes:

  - `*` I force an exit from the scraping then also.
  - `**` The primary key is just a ID (`VARCHAR(10)`) which I scrape from the pages.
  - `***` Number of common characters

Comment: use base64_encode() to give us binary safe strings, one before and after db problem.

Comment: @chris Base64 encoded version of scraped (duplicate) string: `SW50ZXJwZXJzb25hbCBjb21tdW5pY2F0aW9uOyBDb21tdW5pY2F0aW9uIGluIGdyb3VwcyBhbmQgdGVhbXMuIExlYWRlcnNoaXAgYW5kIG1vdGl2YXRpb24gYXMgY3JpdGljYWwgZmFjdG9ycyBpbiB0aGUgbWFuYWdlbWVudCBvZiBlZmZlY3RpdmUgY29tbXVuaWNhdGlvbi4gIFRoZSBlc3NlbnRpYWwgY29tcG9uZW50cyBvZiBlZmZlY3RpdmUgcmVwb3J0IHdyaXRpbmcgYW5kIGVuaGFuY2UgcHJlc2VudGF0aW9uIHNraWxscy4gQ29tbXVuaWNhdGlvbiBza2lsbHMgYXMgYW4gZWZmZWN0aXZlIHRvb2wgZm9yIG1hbmFnaW5nIGNoYW5nZS4=`.

Comment: @chris Base64 encoded version of original string (after being retrieved from DB): `SW50ZXJwZXJzb25hbCBjb21tdW5pY2F0aW9uOyBDb21tdW5pY2F0aW9uIGluIGdyb3VwcyBhbmQgdGVhbXMuIExlYWRlcnNoaXAgYW5kIG1vdGl2YXRpb24gYXMgY3JpdGljYWwgZmFjdG9ycyBpbiB0aGUgbWFuYWdlbWVudCBvZiBlZmZlY3RpdmUgY29tbXVuaWNhdGlvbi4gVGhlIGVzc2VudGlhbCBjb21wb25lbnRzIG9mIGVmZmVjdGl2ZSByZXBvcnQgd3JpdGluZyBhbmQgZW5oYW5jZSBwcmVzZW50YXRpb24gc2tpbGxzLiBDb21tdW5pY2F0aW9uIHNraWxscyBhcyBhbiBlZmZlY3RpdmUgdG9vbCBmb3IgbWFuYWdpbmcgY2hhbmdlLg==`

Comment: @chris Before going into the database, both strings (after Base64 encoding) equate to `SW50ZXJwZXJzb25hbCBjb21tdW5pY2F0aW9uOyBDb21tdW5pY2F0aW9uIGluIGdyb3VwcyBhbmQgdGV‌​hbXMuIExlYWRlcnNoaXAgYW5kIG1vdGl2YXRpb24gYXMgY3JpdGljYWwgZmFjdG9ycyBpbiB0aGUgbWFu‌​YWdlbWVudCBvZiBlZmZlY3RpdmUgY29tbXVuaWNhdGlvbi4gIFRoZSBlc3NlbnRpYWwgY29tcG9uZW50c‌​yBvZiBlZmZlY3RpdmUgcmVwb3J0IHdyaXRpbmcgYW5kIGVuaGFuY2UgcHJlc2VudGF0aW9uIHNraWxscy‌​4gQ29tbXVuaWNhdGlvbiBza2lsbHMgYXMgYW4gZWZmZWN0aXZlIHRvb2wgZm9yIG1hbmFnaW5nIGNoYW5‌​nZS4=`

Answer (score 0):

TEXT fields are subject to character set conversion as/when MySQL sees fit. However, MySQL will not randomly add/remove data without a reason. While text fields DO store the length of the data as 2 extra bytes at the head of the on-disk data blob containing the text field data, those 2 bytes are NEVER exposed to the end user. Assuming character set settings are the same  throughout the client->database->on-disk->database->client pipeline, there should never be a change in string length anywhere.